# Position footcite lower on slide in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, bibtex

I'm having a problem with one of my citations. I have a footnote on a slide, but I want to push it further down on the slide so that I can make room for my `TikZ` figure. What can I do to move the footcite closer to the margin so my figure would have a bit more room?

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    %\documentclass[notes]{beamer}
    %\documentclass[notes=only]{beamer}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{pifont}
    %\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
    \usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
    \setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Huge}
    \useoutertheme{metropolis}
    \useinnertheme{metropolis}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usecolortheme{spruce}
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
    \setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
    \usepackage{multimedia}
    
    \date{}
    \graphicspath{ {./images/} }
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
    \AtBeginBibliography{\footnotesize}
    \appto\bibsetup{\scriptsize}
    \AtEveryCitekey{\iffootnote{\color{red}\scriptsize}{\color{blue}}}
    %\setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}
    \addbibresource{Presentation.bib}
    \usepackage{physics}
    \usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tikz-dimline,calc}
    
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
        decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
        matrix,shapes.symbols, shadows}
    
    \tikzset{
    >=stealth',
      punktchain/.style={
      drop shadow,
        rectangle,
        rounded corners,
        fill=black!10,
        draw=black, thin,
        text width=10em,
        minimum height=3em,
        text centered,
        on chain},
      line/.style={draw, thin, <-},
      element/.style={
        drop shadow,
        tape,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
        minimum width=8em,
        draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
        text width=10em,
        minimum height=3.5em,
        text centered,
        on chain},
      every join/.style={->, thin,shorten >=1pt},
      decoration={brace},
      tuborg/.style={decorate},
      tubnode/.style={midway, right=2pt},
    }
    
    \begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{frame}[t]{\Large{Introduction}} % SLIDE 2
    \begin{block}{What is Mathematical Programming?}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item[\ding{226}] Real-life {\textit{optimization}} problem's that cannot be solved via classic methods are formulated into mathematical programming problems.\footfullcite{youtube}
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{block}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [node distance=.8cm,
      start chain=going below,scale=.40,transform shape]
         \node[punktchain, join] (intro) {Real World Problem};
         \node[punktchain, join] (probf)      {Modeling};
         \node[punktchain, join] (investeringer)      {Anaylsis};
         \node[punktchain, join] (perfekt) {Solution to Problem};
         \node[punktchain, join, ] (emperi) {Interpretation};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \end{frame}
    
    
    
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
    \end{frame}
    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With small changes in definitions of the nodes styles and `node distance` your image with use of the `\small` font size can nicely fine on slide:

**Edit (1):**
Now considering used beamer themes. Unfortunately I can't reproduce result of `\footfullcite`, I simulate it by `\footnote` with approximately the same text length. desired color and font size. Now the footnote had to be manually *push down* for example for `2ex` and figure *pull up* for the same amount.

**Edit (2):**

- In your beamer set up you have duplicate of `\usetheme` with different options. Remove the second one
- The `\setbeamerfont{title}` has no effect, you can delete it.
- Added is `\setbeamerfont{footnote}` for mimic `\footfullcite` and `\setbeamercolor{footnote}` that footnote is the same color as should be  `\footfullcite`.
- Regarding style definition: I overtook almost all your definition . In them I made some small changes:

  - Define common style `base` for nodes, which is used in all other nodes. By this nodes have the same common style (border line thick, text width, align of text, font size, drop shadow and are put on chain) and code for nodes style are shorter..
  - That height of nodes is independent from characters in node text, at end of text is added `\vphantom{g}` by use of option `execute at end node` (see MWE below).
  - Other styles options are the same as in your MWE, eventually are written in a different order.
- Names of options are self-explanatory. Their meanings are thoroughly described in the Ti*k*Z package documentation, chapter "17 Nodes and Edges".

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\huge}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]


\usepackage{multimedia}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-dimline}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\AtBeginBibliography{\footnotesize}
\appto\bibsetup{\scriptsize}
\AtEveryCitekey{\iffootnote{\color{red}\scriptsize}{\color{blue}}}
%\setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}
\addbibresource{Presentation.bib}


\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                calc, chains,
                matrix,
                decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,
                positioning,
                shadows, shapes, shapes.geometric, shapes.symbols, 
                trees}

\tikzset{
    >=stealth',
  punktchain/.style = {draw, thin,rounded corners, fill=black!10, drop shadow,
                       text width=10em, align=center, font=\small,
                       on chain},
       line/.style = {draw, thin, <-},
    element/.style = {tape, draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
                      top color=white,  bottom color=blue!50!black!60!, drop shadow,
                      text width=10em, minimum height=3.5em, align=center,
                      on chain},
 every join/.style = {->, thin, shorten >=1pt},
        decoration = {brace},
     tuborg/.style = {decorate},
    tubnode/.style = {midway, right=2pt},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Introduction} % SLIDE 2
\begin{block}{What is Mathematical Programming?}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[\ding{226}] Real-life {\textit{optimization}} problem's that cannot be solved via classic methods are formulated into mathematical programming problems.\footnote{Some long text which simulate citation of bib entry "Wen Shen: Linear Programing, Lecture 1. Introduction, simple models, graphics solution."}%\footfullcite{youtube}
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%scale=.40, transform shape,
node distance = 4mm,
  start chain = going below
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={punktchain, join}]
\node   (intro)             {Real World Problem};
\node   (probf)             {Modeling};
\node   (investeringer)     {Anaylsis};
\node   (perfekt)           {Solution to Problem};
\node   (emperi)            {Interpretation};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\vspace{2ex}        % <--- added vertical space between figure and `\cite` at bottom of frame
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really like the improvement on the tikz diagram. It matches the block much better now. This didn't really help my problem. I still have the diagram butting up directly against my footcite. I'll try to upload an updated example.

Comment: @MaxBudnick, sorry, a frame content which you show us, in question, is placed on slide nicely.  So it is not clear now, what is your problem.  Hopefully you are aware, that you cannot put an elephant in lady suitcase ....

Comment: Haha. I like your analogy. Yes. I see in your picture it does, but in my example image my citation is also included. The citation takes up more space once it's compiled with your tikz edits. It ends up with the same spacing. Unfortunately, I did not format my code example with the citation that is included in the image. I wasn't sure how to do that directly in the preamble.

Comment: @MaxBudnick, sorry, I just now notice that in my answer I didn't consider `beamer` themes which you use. Adidng them I reproduce your problem. For solve it I manually insert small vertical space (`2ex`)  after figure (see edited answer).

Comment: Thank you! I really like your tikz edits. I also got some insight on proper formatting, Why did you write your code as `punktchain/.style = ` , & `line/.style = ` etc. ? Can you provide some insight into that? Thank you.

Comment: @MaxBudnick, I copy your style definition and make small changes in them. See explanation id Edit (2).

Answer (score 2):

The footnote was already at the bottom of the margin. Some suggestions for you:

1. Using `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}...\end{center}` will remove some extra space before the tikz.
2. You could use `\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{\vspace{-0.5cm}}{}` in the preamble to reduce the bottom margin. However this will apply to every frame.
3. Add some negative vertical space (e.g. `\vspace{-0.2cm}`) before the block env.
4. Using smaller font size for the text.

> I don't know why you said none of those are worked, here is example that I fully reproduce you problem. I add the `.bib` file using `\begin{filecontents*}...\end{filecontents*}` at the top of `tex` file. I use all methods that I mentioned in the answer. I also add frame with `showframe` package. In this case, you can see you almost use the full space vertically. You cannot get more space than this.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{Presentation.bib}
@online{youtube,
title = {Linear Programing, Lecture 1. Introduction, simple models, graphics solution},
date = {2020},
organization = {Youtube},
author = {Wen Shen},
url = {https://www.youtube.be/TxidmVD90EM?t=32},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{beamer}
%\documentclass[notes]{beamer}
%\documentclass[notes=only]{beamer}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
%\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Huge}
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\usepackage{multimedia}

\date{}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\AtBeginBibliography{\footnotesize}
\appto\bibsetup{\scriptsize}
\AtEveryCitekey{\iffootnote{\color{red}\scriptsize}{\color{blue}}}
%\setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}
\addbibresource{Presentation.bib}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-dimline,calc}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols, shadows}

\tikzset{
>=stealth',
  punktchain/.style={
  drop shadow,
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    fill=black!10,
    draw=black, thin,
    text width=10em,
    minimum height=3em,
    text centered,
    on chain},
  line/.style={draw, thin, <-},
  element/.style={
    drop shadow,
    tape,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
    minimum width=8em,
    draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
    text width=10em,
    minimum height=3.5em,
    text centered,
    on chain},
  every join/.style={->, thin,shorten >=1pt},
  decoration={brace},
  tuborg/.style={decorate},
  tubnode/.style={midway, right=2pt},
}
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{\vspace{-1cm}}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{\Large{Introduction}}% SLIDE 2
\vspace{-0.5cm}\begin{block}{What is Mathematical Programming?}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item[\ding{226}] Real-life {\textit{optimization}} problem's that cannot be solved via classic methods are formulated into mathematical programming problems.\footfullcite{youtube}
\end{enumerate}
\end{block}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [node distance=.8cm,
  start chain=going below,scale=.40,transform shape]
     \node[punktchain, join] (intro) {Real World Problem};
     \node[punktchain, join] (probf)      {Modeling};
     \node[punktchain, join] (investeringer)      {Anaylsis};
     \node[punktchain, join] (perfekt) {Solution to Problem};
     \node[punktchain, join, ] (emperi) {Interpretation};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And output:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately none of these worked. `\centering` pushed it further down into the footcite. Adding to beamer template made no noticeable changes. The vspace before the block environment also shifted everything in the document up including the footcite.

Comment: @Max See my new edits in the answer.

Comment: thank you. Now I see how to do the bib citation in the preamble.